# When using web.config transforms, what goes into the base web.config file?

Tags: .net, web-config, web.config-transform

We have

`web.config`

`web.debug.config`

`web.live.config`

If we had something common to both live and debug, such as a setting, I can see that it'd go into `web.config`. Then it'd appear in the output for both debug and live.

But what happens if you have something like an app setting, for example

`<add key="environment" value="myservice.live.com" />`
`<add key="environment" value="myservice.testing.com" />`

We are wondering if you can/should put the key into the base `web.config` with no value `value=""` and transform it in the other configs, or if we should omit the key entirely from the base web.config and add it in the debug/live configs. This might make transformations more tricky as we have to use locators to add values rather than just replace.

Does the raw `web.config` file ever get used by itself?

We're trying to establish how we should be setting up our solution to minimise confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK web.config transformations when deploying the application.

So when running locally in the debugger, you will need the relevant settings in the base web.config file.